# Cannot make grpc-gateway .gw.pb and there is no error

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, grpc-gateway

I've written this simple go server and client which client sends two numbers, and the server replies with the sum, and it works. Now I'm trying to set up a grpc-gateway using grpc API configuration and change the client's request from GRPC to rest.

I am using this [tutorial](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/grpcapiconfiguration.html) and in the below section, I can not create gw, while there is no error:

```sh
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
  -I$GOPATH/src \
  -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis \
  --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true,grpc_api_configuration=path/to/your_service.yaml:. \
  path/to/your_service.proto
```

I used this:

```sh
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I.   -I$GOPATH/src   -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true,grpc_api_configuration=$GOPATH/src/grpc-test/sum.yaml:. ./sum.proto
```

and after this problem I searched and I found this way, which is neither working (no error and no output!):

```sh
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I$GOPATH/src -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-gateway=$GOPATH/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway  --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true,grpc_api_configuration=sum.yaml:. ./sum.proto
```

I run this in the grpc-test directory which has the below tree:

[image: grpc-test tree]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
so this is my sum.yaml:

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

http:
  rules:
    - selector: example.YourService.Echo
      post: /v1/example/echo
      body: "*"
```

And this is sum.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";


service ComputeSum {
    rpc ComputeSum (SumRequest) returns (ResultReply) {
    }
}

message SumRequest {
    int32 firstOperand = 1;
    int32 secondOperand = 2;
}

message ResultReply {
    int32 result = 1;
}
```

Comment: please complete your question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the selector in, it should be `ComputeSum.ComputeSum`.
I asked this question in grpc-channel in [Gophers slack](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjrhc_QwNrnAhXD-6QKHavZDXYQFjABegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgophers.slack.com%2Fmessages%2Fgeneral%2F&usg=AOvVaw0Xu2neY3fHOgQEWFXJ8o8E), and Johan Brandhorst helped me with this.